# Collapsible fieldsets in form using button

Tags: forms

How can I make a button collapse a fieldset in my custom form? I tried the following which did not seem to work:

```
$form['stepone']['next'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t('Next'),
    '#name' => 'nextone',
    '#weight' => 1, 
    '#submit' => array('collapse_next'),
    );
```

The function is:

```
function collapse_next($form, &$form_state){
    if(isset($form_state['values']['nextone'])){
    $form['stepone']['#collapsed'] = TRUE;
    $form['steptwo']['image']['#collapsed'] = FALSE;
    return $form;       
    }
}
```

Comment: "did not seem to work" is very vague. How did you expected it to work? What actually happened? Why built-in functionality wasn't sufficient for you? Why you seem not to use neither AJAX not JS, when the changes you want to happen are client-side ones? And so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I figured this one out!** If anyone needs, I am attaching my method. I added the following into my form:

```
'#prefix' => '<class ="panel-collapse collapse fade" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#name">
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use jquery for this. give some id to your button and on button click trigger the default fieldset collase or use toggle to hide show fieldset. Hope this help!